# act on a single object

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

We have a timer and we want to stop one of the timer when one of the GPIO goes to 1

so far we have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Tkinter import *
import time
from functools import partial
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

class Chronometre(Frame):  # definition de la class'Chronomètre' dans Frame                                                            
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):    # definition initiale de la class   
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
        self._start = 0.0      
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0
        self._running = 0
        self.timestr = StringVar()             
        self.makeWidgets()    

    def makeWidgets(self): #definition pour afficher le temps                       
        l = Label(self, textvariable=self.timestr)
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        l.pack(fill=X, expand=NO, pady=10, padx=10)                    

    def _update(self): # definition du reset
        self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        self._timer = self.after(50, self._update)

        if(GPIO.input(22) ==1):
            print("Faux Départ!")

        if(GPIO.input(24) ==1):
            self.Stop()

        if(GPIO.input(23) ==1):
            self.Stop()

    def _setTime(self, elap): #définition du temps en minutes/secondes/millisecondes
        minutes = int(elap/60)
        seconds = int(elap - minutes*60.0)
        hseconds = int((elap - minutes*60.0 - seconds)*100)              
        self.timestr.set('%02d:%02d:%03d' % (minutes, seconds, hseconds))

    def Start(self, event=None): #lancement du chrono s'il est en arrêt                                                   
        if not self._running:          
            self._start = time.time() - self._elapsedtime
            self._update()
            self._running = 1      

    def Stop(self): # arrêt du chrono s'il est en marche                                  
        if self._running:
            self.after_cancel(self._timer)          
            self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start  
            self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
            self._running = 0

    def Reset(self): # remise à zéro du chrono                               
        self._start = time.time()       
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0  
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)

    def get(self) :
        return self._running


def start_chronos(chronos, event):
    for chrono in chronos:
        chrono.Start()

def reset_chronos(chronos, event):
    for chrono in chronos:
        chrono.Reset()

def stop_chrono_gauche(chrono, event):
    chrono.Stop()

def stop_chrono_droit(chrono, event):
    chrono.Stop()

def main(): # definition de la fenetre de tkinter
    root = Tk()
    root.title('projet 2014-2015')
    chronoDroit = Chronometre(root)
    chronoDroit.pack(side=LEFT,padx=30,pady=30)
    chronoGauche = Chronometre(root)
    chronoGauche.pack(side=RIGHT,padx=30,pady=30)

    root.bind('<a>', partial(start_chronos, (chronoDroit, chronoGauche)))
    root.bind('<z>', partial(stop_chrono_gauche, (chronoDroit)))
    root.bind('<e>', partial(stop_chrono_droit, (chronoGauche)))
    root.bind('<r>', partial(reset_chronos, (chronoDroit, chronoGauche)))

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN)

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

we are trying to get it so that the timers stop independently from each other, but both of them are stopping at the same time

we know that the problem is with `self.Stop()` but we have no clue what to replace it with

how could we make this work?

Comment: As a quick note on your code - Python has `True` and `False` - using `1` and `0` as booleans isn't great for readability, I suggest using the more readable option and doing `self._running = True`, etc...

Comment: Also, you say you *are trying to get it so that the timers stop independently from each other*, but don't state what the problem is, exactly (presumably they are all stopping at once?) - try to make your question as clear as possible. What is happening and how does it differ from what you **want** to happen?

Comment: @Lattyware I've added it, you're right, it does stop both of them

Comment: What is your expected behavior? You want only one, but which one? In `_update()`, you check if the GPIO is set and stop if it is. If `_update()` is being called in both continuously, they will both see the set pin and stop. If you want them to function differently, they need to have different behaviors (maybe pass the pin to stop on as an argument in the constructor, and store it to check against each update? e.g: `if(GPIO.input(self._stop_gpio) == 1): self.Stop())`).

Comment: Wild guess: replace your Z and E bindings with `root.bind('<z>', chronoDroit.stop); root.bind('<e>', chronoGauche.stop)`.

Comment: @Lattyware if the GPIO 24 goes to 1, it needs to stop the right timer, if it's the GPIO 23 goes to 1, it needs to stop the left timer

Comment: @Kevin these work fine, the problem is with the GPIO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that all your objects check both GPIOs, and stop on either one - if you want your objects to have different behaviour, they have to be different. The easiest way to do this is to tell each object what GPIO it should check when you construct it. As a condensed example:

```
class Chronometre(Frame):                                                           
    def __init__(self, gpio, parent=None, **kw):  
        ...
        self._stop_gpio = gpio
    ...
    def _update(self):
        ...
        if(GPIO.input(self._stop_gpio) == 1):
            self.Stop()

...

chronoDroit = Chronometre(23, root)
chronoGauche = Chronometre(24, root)
```

Comment: Was about to suggest something similar

Comment: I get this error `non-default argument follows default argument`

Comment: when I do `def __init__(self, gpio, parent=None, **kw): ` instead I get `int object has no attribute tk`

Comment: @Mranth0ny62 My mistake. Swapping the arguments is correct, but you then need to also swap the arguments where you construct your instances. Updated.

Comment: I don't have the raspberry pi anymore but I'll try tomorrow as soon as I get it back